# how to fetch process id of Oracle WebLogic server and pass it to jmxterm open command

Tags: shell

I am monitoring oraclewebLogic server by using `jmxterm`, I have written a shell script to monitor this,  the after executing shell script i get inside `jmxterm` I should give a `pid` of particular server which I would like to monitor..  now I am reading JMX commands from other .txt file.
and below is the code

```
#Jmx
/usr/bin/java -jar /home/avk03/ALLServers/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar < /home/avk03/ALLServers/WebLogic.txt > /home/avk03/ALLServers/oracleWeblogic.txt

#webLogic.txt
open 23489
beans
domain java.lang
beans
bean java.lang:type=Memory
get -b type=Memory -d java.lang
```

here I want to pass pid dynamically to jmxterm

Comment: show us those script, and how you're getting pid

Comment: @darva I am getting pid by linux command i.e ps -aux|grep weblogic

Comment: and can you show us this script which you are using to monitor? is it bash script?